# Query in SQL Server where field = N'0'

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause

I have some queries where I'm not familiar with, maybe all of you can explain it, please

```
Select * 
From TableA 
Where field1 = N'FAIL' And field2 = N'0'
```

`N'FAIL'` or `N'0'` => what does that mean? Can we use that condition to get more efficient query?

Is this query the same as this?

```
select * 
from TableA 
where field1 = 'FAIL' and field2 = '0'
```

I hope I can get some answers, thank you

Comment: The N-prefix means it's a national character literal (Unicode).

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: if you use nvarchar/nchar as your data type then it's better to use N before literal to avoid implicit conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`N'FAIL'` is a literal **`NVARCHAR`**. `'FAIL'` is a literal **`VARCHAR`**.

Those are two different datatypes: both are variable-length strings (with a maximum length), however `NVARCHAR` stores both Unicode and non-Unicode characters, while `VARCHAR` supports non-Unicode characters only. The storage size of `NVARCHAR` is bigger if you have Unicode characters (2 bytes per character in Unicode, vs 1 byte per character in non-Unicode).

Which one should be used in your statement depends on the actual datatype of the column that the value is compared against. If the column is `NVARCHAR`, use `NVACHAR` literals, else use `VARCHAR`; using the proper datatype for literal strings is always more efficient, and safer as well.